# How does Flask_SQLAlchemy know which Models Classes you've defined

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using `flask` with `flask_sqlalchemy` and I'm a bit perplexed.

This code runs but when you run `db.create_all()` the database you get is empty with not tables.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

class Urls(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    zone = db.Column(db.Integer, default=10, nullable=False)
```

**The fix** is to push the definition of the `Users` class above the `db.create_all()` line. Then you get a database with the `users` table inside it.

My Question is how can `db.create_all()` know that the `Users` class is now defined.
is `create_all` somehow importing the file again?

**Furthermore** how does it know to use Urls and not any other class.
This seems like black magic to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you approach this by finding and reading the `flask_sqlalchemy` source, it might well appear to be black magic. That's not easy code to follow for someone new to Python. The `sqlalchemy` source is even deeper magic.

A somewhat simpler question is to answer is how a given class can locate its subclasses. For that, Python classes have a special `__subclasses__` method that returns a list of (weak) references to immediate subclasses. With that and a bit of extra work, it's possible to walk a tree of subclasses.

For example, if Bar is a subclass of Foo:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass
... 
>>> Foo.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Bar'>]
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html near the bottom.